# How to tell javascript x.value = $('‪#‎selectID‬ option:selected').text(); that 'selectID' is not a name of an ID but rather a variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a while loop that displays a series of select elements.

```
$i = 0;

while(condition)
{
    <input type = 'hidden' id = 'hide' value = ' '>
    <select id = '$i' onchange = 'gettext(this.id)'></select>
    <option></option>
    ...
    ....
    $i++;
}

function gettext(selectID)
{
    var x = document.getElementById('hide');
    x.value = $('‪#‎selectID‬ option:selected').text();
}
```

Now, I need to get the selected text chosen by the user. How should I tell the javascript/jquery that the 'selectID' is not a name of an id of some element-that the selectID is a variable which holds the value of an ID of a select element that I want to get the text from.

Comment: something like '#' + selectID + 'option:selected'?

Comment: id = 'hide' inside the loop, need unique id for every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
$('‪#' + ‎selectID‬ + ' option:selected').text();
```

Simply concatenate your variable as part of the name.

Comment: Have you checked that there is a space between id and option? I accidently missed it

Comment: whoa! that was like magic. thank you very much! you don't know how loud i was when i saw the output. thanks, man! i actually wasted 5hrs on this. thank you very much, i just wanted to tell you that this is part of our thesis so again, thank you so much! :)

Comment: Well, it makes me happy that it actually worked ^^ Would be great if you could mark this question as correct